# Question with 0 votes but too many answers

Tags: discussion, feature-request

There is a possibility of having equal number of up votes and down votes in such type of questions (showing 0 votes), say both are 'n'. Is there any way of finding the magnitude of 'n'?

I think it will make the question more interesting and catchy if some how 'n' is made public.

P.S. Don't forget to consider the fact that it has too many answers(not a worthless question).

Comment: It might be a good idea to include a link to the [question](http://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/76274/how-can-i-build-a-nuclear-reactor-in-my-backyard) that you are referencing, so that readers of this post can easily see what you are talking about.

Comment: Umm sorry but I don't know how to do that. Will copying the address from browser do it? BTW you are right, I am referencing to my question only :P. Hihihi

Comment: You can add a link by using the following MarkUp: [This is the text that is shown](this/is/the/link/used). And you can use the little "edit"-button at the end of your text to edit your post.

Comment: Yes, copy the URL from the browser, or use the `share` button under the post to get a URL for a specific answer.

Comment: I didn't up-vote this question because I appreciated the irony of it not having any votes.  At least that was the case when it didn't have any votes....

Comment: Just a thought on the "not a worthless question" aspect - the number of answers is not a good measurement of how worthless a question is. If a question get a lot of attention, it can mean that it's a good question, but it can just as well mean that it's a bad one. If it's possible to write e.g., 20 unique answers to a question, then it's not really a good question as it's too open and the answers risk needing to be judged subjectively. In contrast, if there is only few answers, then it can just as well be a very well formulated question where no further answers are necessary.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a privilege that you can acquire at 1.000 reputation: [Established User](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/established-user).

It allows you to view the amount of Up- and Downvotes on any question on WorldBuilding.SE. If you get a total of 1.000 reputation you can see how many people voted up and down, so in a sense it is already public to those users that have the required reputation.

Comment: 1000 reps!! That's disappointing. :(

Comment: @killerJONES Don't be disappointed, you will reach the 1.000 at some point. It's an incentive to keep moving forward.

Answer (score 2):

As another [answer](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4771/28) says, viewing vote breakdowns is a privilege that comes when you get a little more rep.

If you really want to know about a specific case and it's a recent post, though, you can work it out from your reputation history.  (For older questions this would require a lot more digging.)  Click on your user name and then click on the "reputation" tab.  This shows you the breakdown of all votes you received per post per day (plus anything else that affected your reputation, like approved edits).  You can count it up from there.

The information is actually available through the Stack Exchange API and I know there's a user script out there somewhere that fetches the data, so even without 1000 rep you can see the vote breakdowns.  The reason the don't just give this to everybody is that using it creates extra load on the servers -- and while your one mouse click might not seem like a big deal to you, added up over the millions of visits per month (across the network), it's more significant.